# How to install Adventure Works DB on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: sql

I have downloaded the free Express version of SQL Server 2017 onto my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine. I have created a test database through the command line terminal, and I was able to create a table and also managed to insert data into the table.

What I need now, is to download the sample AdventureWorks database (or it seems that WideWorldImporters is now the "new" sample db), so that I can play around and get used to SQL querying. Does anyone know if I can download and install the AdventureWorks (or WideWorldImporters) database onto my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 4):

You can download the sample database here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/download/adventureworks/AdventureWorks2017.bak

Now, restore the database:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorks2017]  
FROM DISK = N'/YOUR_DOWNLOAD_PATH/AdventureWorks2017.bak'  
WITH MOVE 'AdventureWorks2017'  
TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/AdventureWorks2017.mdf',  
MOVE 'AdventureWorks2017_log'  
TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/AdventureWorks2017.ldf';    
GO
```